# Archivo HTML error en el texto

Tags: html

Tengo un archivo con extensión HTML que contiene errores. En vez de estar las palabras escritas correctamente aparece esto: �.

El archivo me llega así y no es posible arreglarlo desde el origen.
Por eso, estoy buscando otras soluciones.

Edito: Puedo acceder al contenido del archivo.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Saludos. Ya que "no es una solución arreglarlo desde el origen"; abrelo en un editor de texto y sabiendo la palabra que esta mal escrita usa la opción **reemplazar** para cambiar ya sea la letra/símbolo que sale mal por el correcto. Lo siguiente no lo he realizado, pero mira al inicio si tiene `utf-8` y lo cambias por `ISO-8859-1` o viceversa.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr Hola, el archivo es muy extenso y contiene muchos errores. Además son varios archivos, reemplazarlo individualmente se convertiría en una ardua tarea. Por ello busco una forma de 'corregirlo' con código y así automatizarlo. La segunda opción que propones no me da resultado, ¿puede que sea porque el archivo está así desde el inicio?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base)

Comment: @BetaM El archivo lo tengo tal cual con ese carácter, no me llega de base de datos, es estático. Gracias de todas formas

Comment: Entonces si no hay acceso al archivo será prácticamente imposible y la pregunta será cerrada como un problema que no se puede reproducir

Comment: Puedo acceder al archivo y a su contenido. Me refiero que no lo obtengo de base de datos si se modifica/actualiza.
Estoy buscando coger cada palabra y compararlas con un diccionario (o algo así) y la que tenga error, modificarla. O si hay un sistema de 'completado' que detecte la letra que falta. Igual es imposible como me dices y le estoy dando demasiadas vueltas.

Comment: Que te digo deberías indicar algún intento por qué así como lo mencionas también es motivo de cierre por ser basada en opiniones

Comment: @BetaM ¿Qué quieres decir?, ¿cómo debería plantear la pregunta?

Comment: Con base a [ask], mostrando no solo el problema sino además que has intentado

Comment: Eso lo tengo claro pero no he intentado nada porque no sé que hacer, por eso la pregunta. Lo que he probado ha sido después de lo que han comentado aquí.

Comment: que sistema operativo tenes ? en linux podés probar con [`iconv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv).  que lenguajes hay disponibles para hacer un batch?  bash, php, python, ruby ?

Comment: Trabajo con Windows 10. Estoy empezando en el mundo de desarrollo así que todo es bastante nuevo para mí.

Comment: [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm) viene con una implementación de iconv para windows, probalo con un par de archivos a ver si sirve y si se te complica armar el batch para procesar todos ya tenes material para editar la pregunta

Answer (score -1):

generalmente esto pasa cuando una palabra tiene tilde o en la ñ, si no quieres utilizar utf iso intenta con esto.

```
 á -> &aacute;
 é -> &eacute;
 í -> &iacute;
 ó -> &oacute;
 ú -> &uacute;
 ñ -> &ntilde;
```

ejemplo

```
    <h1>a&ntildeadir</h1>
```

o también puedes añadir el utf o iso

```
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8″ />
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1″ />
```

Comment: La opción que me indicas la han comentado antes pero no me funciona ninguno de los dos.

Comment: puedes entrar al inspector de codigo para mostrarme el error